# Could not get unknown property 'Delete' for root project 'MyApplication3' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: java, android, gradle

Android studio 3.1.2 -> new project -> build failed with following problems in log :

```
Could not get unknown property 'Delete' for root project 'MyApplication3' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
Open File
```

Here is the build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The last three lines are the problem. Its added by default.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

try to past this code : in app Laval app.gradle , not in top-level.

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Can you say why it is in top level by default? And what its purpose if I need to add it on app level?